# Path markup syntax for PathGeometry

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Using [path markup syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx), you can easily create `Path`s with custom shapes like a diamond:

```
<Path Data="M 0,5 L 5,0 L 10,5 L 5,10 Z" />
```

Is it possible to use this syntax in a [`PathGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.PathGeometry_properties(v=vs.95).aspx)?  Per the link above (which is for WPF and not Silverlight), I tried using `PathGeometry.Figures`:

```
<local:SomeControl>
    <local:SomeControl.Geometry>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M 0,5 L 5,0 L 10,5 L 5,10 Z" />
    </local:SomeControl.Geometry>
</local:SomeControl>
```

but this throws a `XamlParseException`

> failed to create a 'PathGeometry.Figures' from the text 'M 0,5 L 5,0 L 10,5 L 5,10 Z'

Do I really need to use the extended form below, or is there some way to use the short string?

```
<PathGeometry>
    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,5" IsClosed="True" IsFilled="True">
        <LineSegment Point="5,0" />
        <LineSegment Point="10,5" />
        <LineSegment Point="5,10" />
    </PathFigure> 
</PathGeometry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that the Blend SDK has a [ConvertToPathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.drawing.core.geometryhelper.converttopathgeometry(v=expression.40).aspx) helper method.  So it would be easy to create an `IValueConverter` using this:

```
return GeometryHelper.ConvertToPathGeometry((string)parameter);
```

And then the Geometry could be set to a `PathGeometry` instance like this:

```
<local:SomeControl Geometry="{Binding ConverterParameter='M 0,5 L 5,0 L 10,5 L 5,10 Z',
                                      Converter={StaticResource PathGeometryConverter}}"
                                  />
```

Comment: How to reference `ConvertToPathGeometry` in the xaml resources? What is the absolute path of it's containing file?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad it's a static method -- I can't follow you, or imagine the context where you would want to reference this from XAML.